# Schedule Parse Push Notification with PHP without local time

Tags: php, parse-platform, push-notification, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to schedule a Parse Push Notification with PHP. I succesfully create the schedule for the push, but it says local time. I don't want to use local time for the device. I want it to be just 5 minutes from now to everybody. Here is my code:

```
$minutes_to_add = 5;
$time = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$time->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $minutes_to_add . 'M'));
$stamp = $time->format(DateTime::ISO8601);

$date = date_create($stamp);
ParsePush::send(array("channels" => ["Test"], "data" => $data, "push_time" => $date));
```

The results in "Parse.com" are:

> May 17th, 2015 at 5:09 PM local time

How can I get local time out of there?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem. On the documentation it says that if you dont provide timezone, the notification will be in local time, if you provide a timezone, then it is scheduled for the specified timezone. But no matter what i choose, it always sets as local push...

Comment: Maybe you should try  $time = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),new DateTimeZone('UTC'));   But not working for me